# Should the origin of base_link and odom be the same?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many variants of this question and I probably have not stated it precisely. But I am tidying up my Urdf. What is the common sense or conventional way? Should my base_link correspond to the "center" of the robot as a whole (I know this is subjective). Or should it be on the floor/surface? Because publish the transform between odom and my robot, should the transform have the same x and y, but a few centimeters above the floor?

I know "it depends" and there are many ways of doing this. But what's the least surprising way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364415/should-the-origin-of-base_link-and-odom-be-the-same?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2020-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are ROS Enhancement Proposals (REPs) that can be thought of as standards.Check out [REP 105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html)  for a description of platform coordinate frames and [REP 103](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) for axis standards. Your `base_link` should be fixed to your robot, whereas `odom` is 'fixed' to a point in the real world. As your robot moves, the transformation between the two should change: this is how you determine your position.

I've also seen `base_footprint` used, but it's a matter of application and preference.

---

Originally posted by [chives_onion](https://answers.ros.org/users/39292/chives_onion/) with karma: 180 on 2020-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3